# Using PLYR for Youtube videos - poster image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, plyr.js

I am using Plyr (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) to play Youtube videos inline.
But i now want to add a poster to the player, so i can use a thumbnail for the video, before it plays.

Plyr supports this, but i can not get it to work.
I am currently using Plyr in its most simple form:

Youtube video: `<div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>`

Initialize Plyr: `<script>plyr.setup();</script>`

Thats it.
How can i get the above snippet to show a poster for `"/myposter.png"`?

Answer (score 6):

Here is some example to achieve youtube video custom cover image:

`player.poster = '../Images/landing/attendance/Admin Back.png';`

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/fgegfjp7/1/)

or

`var player = new Plyr('#vid');
setTimeout(() => {
    player.poster = 'http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640x360/p03hj5f7.jpg';
}, 500)`

or

you can read this article [A Better Method for Embedding YouTube Videos on your Website](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)

Answer (score -3):

Just use the poster attribute on html5 video tag:

```
<video poster="/myposter.png" controls>
```

check out at https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#html

Comment: This is only for HTML5 videos, it does not work for Youtube or Vimeo